# Chromium crashes when loaded a .html in Java

Tags: java, android, webview, chromium

An app saves html file in Documents > ProTec Games > HTML Editor PRO > *file.html*

Then tries to run the output file in Chromium WebView

What should be the url or code to open this location in Chromium?

The code I have implemented in Java is

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(/storage/emulated/0/Documents/ProTec Games/HTML Editor PRO/index.html));
```

I tried saving file name say *index.html* in a variable "file"